como saber hacer ese slot

gracias espero me puedan ayudar estoy haciendo un formulario bueno me estoy fijando de uno que esta en una pagina pero me encontre con ese slot que sale hay despues de option y no se como se pone y estoy usando una pagina de html ya que mi pc esta muy lenta para ese programa gracias espero me puedan ayudar



<div class="wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-column is-style-offset-up gb-block-layout-column">
<div class="gb-block-layout-column-inner gb-has-custom-background-color" style="padding:20px;background-color:#0404e2">
<div class="wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-columns moving-form gb-layout-columns-1 one-column has-theme-primary-background-color gb-has-custom-text-color" style="padding-top:3%;padding-right:3%;padding-bottom:3%;padding-left:3%;color:#ffffff">
<div class="gb-layout-column-wrap gb-block-layout-column-gap-2 gb-is-responsive-column">
<div class="wp-block-genesis-blocks-gb-column gb-block-layout-column">
<div class="gb-block-layout-column-inner">
<div class="home-quote">
<h1 class="has-text-align-left small-heading is-style-default"> Request a FREE Moving Quote Today!!</h1>
</div>
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper gform_legacy_markup_wrapper gform-theme--no-framework gf_customfields_wrapper" data-form-theme="legacy" data-form-index="0" id="gform_wrapper_1">
<div id="gf_1" class="gform_anchor" tabindex="-1"></div>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="gform_ajax_frame_1" id="gform_1" class="gf_customfields" action="/#gf_1" data-formid="1" novalidate>
<div class="gform-body gform_body">
  <ul id="gform_fields_1" class="gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below validation_below"><li id="field_1_21" class="gfield gfield--type-html gfield_html gfield_htmlformatted gfield_no_follows_desc field_sublabel_below gfield--no-description field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_21"></li>
<div class="bg-home-form first-fields"><ul
class="gfrom_fields top_lab el description_below">
<li id="field_1_10" class="gfield gfield---type-date gfield--input-type-datepicker gfield--datepicker-no-icon gf_left_half gf_date gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below gfield--no-descriptions fiel_description_delow field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_10">
  "Moving Date"
  <span class="gfield_required">
    <span class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk=">*
      <span>
    <span>
      <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_dte">
    <input name="ginput_10" id="input_1_10" type="text" value class="datepicker gfrom-datepicker mdy datepicker-no-icom hasDatepicker initialized" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" aria-describedby="input_1_10_date_format" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" readonly="readonly">
  <span id="input_1_10_date_format" class="screen-reader-text">MM/DD/YYYY
   <span> 
    <input type="hidden" id="gforms_calendar_icon_input_1_10" class="gform_hidden" value="https://9dca5d96.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/datepicker/datepicker.svg">
   <li id="field_1_17" class="gfield gfield--type-select gf_rignt_half gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_17">
  <label class="gfield_label gfrom-field-label" for="input_1_17">
    "size of your move"
   <span class="gfield_required">
     <span class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*
   <span>
     <span>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_select">
   <select name="input_17" id="input_1_17" class="medium gfield_select" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">  
  <option valuealue selected="selected" class="gf_placeholder">-</option>
     <option valuealue="Moving Boxes Only">Moving Boxes Only </option>
   <option value="Studio">Studio</option>
    <option value="1 bedroom Apt">1 Bedroom Apt</option>
    <option value="1 bedroom House">1 Bedroom House</option>
    <option value="2 bedroom Apt">2 Bedroom Apt</option>
    <option value="2 bedroom House">2 Bedroom House</option>
    <option value="3 bedroom Apt">3 Bedroom Apt</option>
     <option value="3 bedroom House">3 Bedroom House</option>
     <option value="4 bedroom Apt">4 Bedroom Apt</option>
     <option value="4 bedroom House">4 Bedroom House</option>
     <option value="5 bedroom Apt">5 Bedroom Apt</option>
     <option value="5 bedroom House">5 Bedroom House</option>
     <option value="6 bedroom Apt">6 Bedroom Apt</option>
     <option value="6 bedroom House">6 Bedroom House</option>
     <option value="6 or more Bed room Apt">6 or more Bedroom Apt</option>
     <option value="6 or more Bed room House">6 or more Bedroom House</option>
  </select>
    </div>
       <li id="field_1_8"class="gfield gfield--type-adrress gf_left_half gf_zip gfield_contains_required field_siblsbel_hidden_label gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_8">
    <option> value="6        
<div class="bg-home-form second-fields">
<ul class="gform_fields top_label description_below">
<li></li>
<li id="field_1_11" class="gfield gfield--type-name gf_left_half gf_name gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_hidden_label gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_11">
<label class="gfield_label gform-field-label gfield_label_before_complex">Size of your Move</label>
<div class="ginput_complex ginput_container ginput_container--name no_prefix has_first_name no_middle_name no_last_name no_suffix gf_name_has_1 ginput_container_name gform-grid-row" id="input_1_11">
<span id="input_1_11_3_container" class="name_first gform-grid-col gform-grid-col--size-auto">
  <label for="input_1_11_3" class="gform-field-label gform-field-label--type-sub hidden_sub_label screen-reader-text">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="input_11.3" id="input_1_11_3" value aria-required="true" placeholder="First Name">
</span>
</div>
</li>
<li id="field_1_18" class="gfield gfield--type-name gf_right_half gf_name gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_hidden_label gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_18">Moving To</li>
<li id="field_1_12" class="gfield gfield--type-phone gf_left_half gf_phone gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_12">Last Name</li>
<li id="field_1_13" class="gfield gfield--type-email gf_right_half gf_mail gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_13">Phone Number</li>
<li id="field_1_23" class="gfield gfield--type-html gfield_html gfield_html_formatted gfield_no_follows_desc field_sublabel_below gfield--no-description field_description_below field_validation_below gfield_visibility_visible" data-js-reload="field_1_23"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul>Email</ul>
</div>
<div class="gform_footer top_label">Email</div>
<p style="display: none !important;" class="akismet-fields-container" data-prefix="ak_">…</p>
</form>
</div>
<iframe style="display:none;width:0px;height:0px;" src="about:blank" name="gform_ajax_frame_1" id="gform_ajax_frame_1" title="This iframe contains the logic required to handle Ajax powered Gravity Forms.">…</iframe>
<script>…</script>



eso es todo lo que he escrito y todos lo que dicen option value le salen ese slot que esta en la foto si quiere pongo una foto mas larga de donde lo estoy copiando

Y ya buscaste eso en Google? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

si quieres te paso todo lo que he escrito pero de donde lo estoy sacando eso no se como ponerlo y te paso lo que he escrito y lo pones en el html t veras como va quedando

Hola @AlexisMelean, ¿para que quisieras crear un slot o solo te interesa saber que es? Más info

@AlexisMelean es que ni siquiera has leído lo que te puse. Estas haciendo todo mal por NO LEER. Lee [ask] y el [tour]. No te cuesta y vas a saber como funciona SOes

@OCHOA de verdad disculpa soy nuevo aqui apenas cree la cuenta no hace mucho me disculpo de verdad :(

Pon el código necesario aquí en la pregunta, a través de un [repro] (énfasis en mínimo), como te habían mencionado. Si te da el error de que tu pregunta es mayormente código, e incluso con el [repro] sigue siendo extenso el código, entonces pon el código como texto normal y otro usuario podrá editar tu pregunta para corregir el formato. No olvides borrar tu no-respuesta, y ser descriptivo en tu pregunta (sin olvidar usar las comas, por cierto) :)

@AlexisMelean yo te entiendo perfectamente. Justo por eso te pasé los links en mi primer comentario, antes de todo. Tu deber como buen desarrollador que buscas ser es leer la "documentación" (para el caso mis links) y hacer lo que en esos textos se explica. Ahí te enteras de todo lo que los nuevos deben aprender sobre SOes. Por ahora solo necesitas hacer todo lo que se te ha dicho en todos los comentarios y no dejar que cierren esta pregunta. Ánimos!

Ese <option> proviene de una Plantilla HTML, una tecnología usada en Componentes Web.

Eso que te muestra encerrado en un cuadrado con bordes redondos se denominan badges o distintivos en español.
Corresponde a información adicional que te muestra el inspector de elementos, tú que estás copiando el código no debes agregar nada en tu código, porque vuelvo a repetir: es información que te está mostrando el navegador (lo coloca el navegador, no es código).
Un slot es comúnmente utilizado junto a un template, este último es una plantilla, donde el slot permite marcar una posición para integrar información. Son elementos que van muy de la mano con una tecnología llamada Web Components la cual permite crear componentes reutilizables utilizando HTML+JS+CSS
Lo interesante del asunto es ¿Por qué marca como slot a los option?
Francamente no tengo respuesta, la inclusión de los badges en el inspector de elementos es relativamente nuevo, pero aun así no recuerdo haber visto que esto pasara antes.
Mi suposición: Es que los select nativos los han convertido internamente a web components. Seguramente para que estos puedan heredar de select. Además, está en carpeta algunos cambios al select para permitir mayor edición sobre ellos, quizás el construirlos como web components sea para facilitar esto, pero son todo suposiciones.

Gracias buscare en YouTube a ver como crear ese formulario es que ese lo estoy agarrando de otro lado pero no me deja copiar y pegar y lo estoy escribiendo y todavía faltan mas cosas por escribir pero bueno yo porque me gusto ese formulario si me pueden regalar uno se los agradecería es que el formulario que tiene mi pagina no me gusta y quisiera ponerle otro que sea mejor gracias por la ayuda

@AlexisMelean En lugar de inspeccionar elemento mira el código de fuente (ctrl+u), ahí podrás copar+pegar fácilmente
